# My left join union right join isn't quite working - I'm trying to simulate a full outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal-8

I am trying to do a full outer join of several tables in Drupal 8. MySQL doesn't support full outer join so I'm using a left join union right join.

It gets most of the data but in the materials that I am querying for, I know there are multiple materials but I am only getting one. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

I am directly accessing the db and not using helper functions because this is actually for a mobile app I am writing, that queries the database from phones or tablets:

```
    $query_phrase = "select 
                     commerce_product_field_data.title as title,
                     commerce_product_field_data.product_id as product_id,
                     commerce_product__8fd244ef14.field_has_multiple_configuration_value as has_multiple_configuration,
                     commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value as barcode,
                     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_number as price,
                     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_currency_code as currency_code,
                     commerce_product__field_sku.field_sku_value as sku,
                     node_field_data.title as material_name,
                     file_managed.uri as uri,
                     file_managed.filename as filename
                     
                     from {commerce_product_field_data}
                     
                     left join commerce_product__8fd244ef14 on product_id = commerce_product__8fd244ef14.entity_id
                     left join commerce_product__field_barcode on product_id = commerce_product__field_barcode.entity_id
                     left join commerce_product__field_price on product_id = commerce_product__field_price.entity_id
                     left join commerce_product__field_sku on product_id = commerce_product__field_sku.entity_id
/*not working*/      left join commerce_product__field_materials  on product_id = commerce_product__field_materials.entity_id
/*not working*/      left join node_field_data on commerce_product__field_materials.field_materials_target_id = node_field_data.nid
                     left join file_managed on product_id = file_managed.fid";

       $query_phrase .= " union ";
                     
    $query_phrase .= "select 
                     commerce_product_field_data.title as title,
                     commerce_product_field_data.product_id as product_id,
                     commerce_product__8fd244ef14.field_has_multiple_configuration_value as has_multiple_configuration,
                     commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value as barcode,
                     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_number as price,
                     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_currency_code as currency_code,
                     commerce_product__field_sku.field_sku_value as sku,
                     node_field_data.title as material_name,
                     file_managed.uri as uri,
                     file_managed.filename as filename
                     
                     from {commerce_product_field_data}
                     
                     right join commerce_product__8fd244ef14 on product_id = commerce_product__8fd244ef14.entity_id
                     right join commerce_product__field_barcode on product_id = commerce_product__field_barcode.entity_id
                     right join commerce_product__field_price on product_id = commerce_product__field_price.entity_id
                     right join commerce_product__field_sku on product_id = commerce_product__field_sku.entity_id
/*not working*/      right join commerce_product__field_materials  on product_id = commerce_product__field_materials.entity_id
/*not working*/      right join node_field_data on commerce_product__field_materials.field_materials_target_id = node_field_data.nid
                     right join file_managed on product_id = file_managed.fid";
                     
       $query_phrase .=  " where commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value = :barcode";
                     
                     
    $query = db_query($query_phrase, array(":barcode" => "334242"));
```

When I debug my results I get:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Dummy Product
    [product_id] => 2
    [has_multiple_configuration] => 0
    [barcode] => 334242
    [price] => 325.000000
    [currency_code] => USD
    [sku] => dummy sku
    [material_name] => test material
    [uri] => public:a
```

But I know I have more than one material.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your post

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `where` clause in the `left join` part of the query.

```
$query_phrase = "select 
     commerce_product_field_data.title as title,
     commerce_product_field_data.product_id as product_id,
     commerce_product__8fd244ef14.field_has_multiple_configuration_value as has_multiple_configuration,
     commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value as barcode,
     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_number as price,
     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_currency_code as currency_code,
     commerce_product__field_sku.field_sku_value as sku,
     node_field_data.title as material_name,
     file_managed.uri as uri,
     file_managed.filename as filename

     from {commerce_product_field_data}

     left join commerce_product__8fd244ef14 on product_id = commerce_product__8fd244ef14.entity_id
     left join commerce_product__field_barcode on product_id = commerce_product__field_barcode.entity_id
     left join commerce_product__field_price on product_id = commerce_product__field_price.entity_id
     left join commerce_product__field_sku on product_id = commerce_product__field_sku.entity_id
     left join commerce_product__field_materials  on product_id = commerce_product__field_materials.entity_id
     left join node_field_data on commerce_product__field_materials.field_materials_target_id = node_field_data.nid
     left join file_managed on product_id = file_managed.fid";

   $query_phrase .=  " where commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value = :barcode";

   $query_phrase .= " union ";

$query_phrase .= "select 
     commerce_product_field_data.title as title,
     commerce_product_field_data.product_id as product_id,
     commerce_product__8fd244ef14.field_has_multiple_configuration_value as has_multiple_configuration,
     commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value as barcode,
     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_number as price,
     commerce_product__field_price.field_price_currency_code as currency_code,
     commerce_product__field_sku.field_sku_value as sku,
     node_field_data.title as material_name,
     file_managed.uri as uri,
     file_managed.filename as filename

     from {commerce_product_field_data}

     right join commerce_product__8fd244ef14 on product_id = commerce_product__8fd244ef14.entity_id
     right join commerce_product__field_barcode on product_id = commerce_product__field_barcode.entity_id
     right join commerce_product__field_price on product_id = commerce_product__field_price.entity_id
     right join commerce_product__field_sku on product_id = commerce_product__field_sku.entity_id
     right join commerce_product__field_materials  on product_id = commerce_product__field_materials.entity_id
     right join node_field_data on commerce_product__field_materials.field_materials_target_id = node_field_data.nid
     right join file_managed on product_id = file_managed.fid";

   $query_phrase .=  " where commerce_product__field_barcode.field_barcode_value = :barcode";
```

Comment: that didn't seem to solve it but it did give me more insite to sql.... i am prolly just going to run 2 querys as much as i didn't want to ... thank you though

Comment: I suspect there's something else wrong. Your mistake would have caused you to get too many rows, not too few. So the problem is in the individual queries in the union.

Comment: You generally shouldn't have conditions on a left-joined table in the `WHERE` clause, since that will filter out all the rows that have no match in that table. The condition should be in the `ON` clause that joins with that table.

Comment: I'm not sure how well the recipe for emulating full outer join works when you have so many tables. You might need more combinations.